# if condition implementation in linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have a list of 100+ folders in a linux at a folder path "files/data" where I already have basic script "list.sh".

```
for d in files/data/*
do
echo $d
done
```

When I run it...

```
sh list.sh
```

It is listing all the 100+ folders (amazon, apple, cola, pepsi, and etc...) in side the "files/data" folder. But I am looking for some if command implementation to achieve the bellow.

When I call...

```
sh list.sh --brand=apple
```

Then it should only list "apple" and if i call...

```
sh list.sh --brand=all
```

Then it should list all the 100+ folders (amazon, apple, cola, pepsi, and etc...).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edit your's script

Usage:

> ./script.sh all - show all dirs in folder path
>
> ./script.sh apple - show apple dirs
>
> You can't use script without parameter because usage of grep.

Hope that's all what you need

```
#!/bin/bash

brand=$1


function ShowDirs()
{
for d in files/data/*
do
    if ! [[ $brand == all ]];
     then
        echo $d | grep $brand
    else
        echo $d
    fi
done
}

ShowDirs
```